# JDBC does not Inserting data into mysql table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have problem with inserting data into mysql table. JDBC doesnt inserting data into mysql table.
JDBC should get value from input "liczbaUzytkownikow" and "data from table form which contains informations about "termin" (Exactly: termin.nazwaObiektu, termin.adresObiektu, termin.dzien, termin.odKtorej and termin.doKtorej).

Here is code of this JDBC:

```
conn = ConnectionClass.Polacz();
ArrayList<Rezerwacja> rezerwacje = new ArrayList<Rezerwacja>();

PreparedStatement st = null;

ResultSet rs = null;
String sql = "INSERT INTO rezerwacje (liczbaUczestnikow,idTermin) values ('" + liczbaUczestnikow + "','" + idTermin + "')"
 + "UPDATE termin SET termin.czyZajety=true WHERE termin.idTermin = '"+ idTermin +"'";              

try
{
    st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);


        rs = st.executeQuery();


    while(rs.next())
    {
        Rezerwacja rezerwacja = new Rezerwacja();
        rezerwacja.setLiczbaUczestnikow(rs.getInt(1));
        rezerwacja.setIdTermin(rs.getInt(2));
        rezerwacje.add(rezerwacja);
    }
}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an SQLException?

Comment: Not really sure. Can i display this error in web browser (for example, forwarding to somePage.jsp in servlet) or console ?

Comment: You can't access your server logs? Instead of printing it out, throw new RuntimeException(e); then you'll see it in the browser or your browser's dev tools if this is ajax.

Comment: can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery(). error. I tried to change it to executeUpdate() but Eclipse tells me to change tipe of ResultSet rs to int.

Comment: So change it? If it's an update, what are you expecting to read out anyway?

Comment: you can´t do "INSERT INTO rezerwacje (liczbaUczestnikow,idTermin) values ('" + liczbaUczestnikow + "','" + idTermin + "')"
         + "UPDATE termin SET termin.czyZajety=true WHERE termin.idTermin = '"+ idTermin +"'";

Answer (score 3):

You should use `PreparedStatement` to avoid sql injection attacks.
Furthermore your sql is wrong:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO rezerwacje (liczbaUczestnikow,idTermin) values ('" + liczbaUczestnikow + "','" + idTermin + "')"
         + "UPDATE termin SET termin.czyZajety=true WHERE termin.idTermin = '"+ idTermin +"'";
```

you cannot execute two different statements in a single batch.
In your case an `Insert` and an `Update`.

Create two `PreparedStatement`'s:

```
String sql1 = "INSERT INTO rezerwacje (liczbaUczestnikow,idTermin) values (?,?)";
String sql2 = "UPDATE termin SET termin.czyZajety=true WHERE termin.idTermin = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
preparedStatement1.setString(1, liczbaUczestnikow );
preparedStatement1.setInt(2, idTerminal);
PreparedStatement preparedStatement2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
preparedStatement2.setInt(1, idTerminal);
preparedStatement1.executeUpdate();
preparedStatement2.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: is preparedStatement2.setInt(1, idTerminal);

Comment: Post before editing works... But, no matter what i type into "liczbaUczestnikow" text input, it always inserts 1 into mysql table.

Comment: and where is the jsp that contains a form, that contains a text input named "liczbaUczestnikow"?

Comment: It's in the same jsp. <div class="tabelawybor">
            <td><b>Wpisz liczbę uczestników:</b><input type="text" name="uczest" /></td>
            <% String liczbaUzytkownikow = request.getParameter("uczest"); %>
        </div>        What's more it always gets idTermin=1.

Comment: that input should be placed inside the form not outside, have a look http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit

Comment: of course. your html form(posted in another question) is completly wrong. I think you will never communicate with your servlet. First of all read a tutorial howto communicate between html and servlets.

Comment: Is it possible to create conversation with you @StefanBeike ?